# Como aplicar filtros em um data.frame?

Tags: r

Tenho uma base de dados no Excel com 12135 dados e nem todos os campos estão preenchidos e alguns indivíduos tem idade negativo e outros tem idade maior que 17 anos e outros com idade maior que 70 anos.

Preciso saber quais funções/filtros do *SOFTWARE* R que solucione estas duas questões:

1° Eliminar todos os que tem algum dados não preenchido (ex: tenho tabela de idade, sexo, unidade orgânica, curso, ano de ingresso.dentro da tabela sexo, não se sabe o sexo de alguns alunos; e outros não se sabe o curso que frequenta assim por diante. Preciso eliminar todos os dados referente a esses alunos e trabalhar só com alunos que tem todos os campos preenchidos);

2° Apresente todas as informações dos alunos com idade de 17 anos a 70 anos, isto é, os outros são eliminados.

Comment: Amigo, desconheço da linguagem R, mas tenho um grande conhecimento em Python! Acredito que R, pelo que eu tenho ouvido falar em palestras, não é muito eficaz no seu caso por ter muitas linhas para processar e levaria mais tempo que em Python. Recomendo a biblioteca Panda no Python para ler e fazer seu dataset.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt! Leia em [Como perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) e [mcve](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para saber como elaborar uma pergunta de facil compreensao e assim poder ser ajudado. Se você colocar o código do que você já tem (data frame, colunas, etc.) vai ser bem mais fácil para a comunidade lhe ajudar.

Comment: @ViniciusMesel, o R consegue lidar facilmente com base de dados com ~12k items; eu já trabalhei com data frames de mais de 1 milhão de dados sem problemas.

Comment: Evandro, mesmo que isso possa ser facilmente feito no R, você também pode fazer sem dificuldades no Excel utilizando a ferramenta de filtro. Se o seu objetivo for usar o R apenas para realizar este filtro, acho que não há necessidade.

Comment: Evandro uma sugestão, mesmo que de modo geral você tenha sido claro, sempre que possível forneça uma amostra representativa dos esses dados, isso que facilita o entendimento e a vida de que vai responder a questão. Além disso, se o caso é só filtrar os dados, concordo com o Molx, o Excel da conta disto.

Comment: Boa tarde. Não sei como postar esse exemplo aqui. É pa um trabalho pedido  na escola e uma das exigências do professor é que seja feita no R. Indica-me como postar um exemplo no SO

Answer (score 1):

Considerando:

```
dados<-data.frame(idade=c(15,18,25,40,85,NA),
              sexo=c("M","F",NA,"F","M","M"),
              unidade.organica=c("EMEI CG","USP",NA,"UFSM","UFRGS","UPF"),
              curso=c("TÉCNICO","SUPERIOR",NA,"SUPERIOR","SUPERIOR",NA),
              ano.ingresso=c(2005,2011,NA,2014,1980,2015))
#exibindo o data.frame criado
dados
  idade sexo unidade.organica    curso ano.ingresso
1    15    M          EMEI CG  TÉCNICO         2005
2    18    F              USP SUPERIOR         2011
3    25 <NA>             <NA>     <NA>           NA
4    40    F             UFSM SUPERIOR         2014
5    85    M            UFRGS SUPERIOR         1980
6    NA    M              UPF     <NA>         2015
```

OBS: leve em conta que seus dados ausentes são representados por NA.

```
##Filtro dos dados ausentes (NA):
#Removendo os NA's com função na.omit()
dada.sem.NA<-na.omit(dados)

#Removendo NA's com a função indexadora which():
dados.sem.NA<-dados[-unique(which(is.na(dados),arr.ind = T)[,1]),]
```

Para ambas as funções:`which()` ou `na.omit()`. O resultado é:

```
 dados.sem.NA    
      idade sexo unidade.organica    curso ano.ingresso
    1    15    M          EMEI CG  TÉCNICO         2005
    2    18    F              USP SUPERIOR         2011
    4    40    F             UFSM SUPERIOR         2014
    5    85    M            UFRGS SUPERIOR         1980
```

O filtro de idade pode ser aplicado em qualquer variável `dados` ou em `dados.sem.NA`, veja os casos:

```
#Filtro de idade na variável dados:
dados.por.idade<-dados[(dados.sem.NA$idade>17 & dados.sem.NA$idade<70), ]
```

O resultado é:

```
dados.por.idade
     idade sexo unidade.organica    curso ano.ingresso
   2    18    F              USP SUPERIOR         2011
   3    25 <NA>             <NA>     <NA>           NA
   6    NA    M              UPF     <NA>         2015

 #Filtro de idade na variável dados.sem.NA:
 dados.por.idade<-dados.sem.NA[(dados.sem.NA$idade>17 & dados.sem.NA$idade<70), ]
```

O resultado é:

```
dados.por.idade
    idade sexo unidade.organica    curso ano.ingresso
  2    18    F              USP SUPERIOR         2011
  4    40    F             UFSM SUPERIOR         2014
```

Espero ter ajudado. Boa sorte!

Comment: Jean, acho que você pode simplifcar o código um pouco. Para omitir os `NA's` você pode utilizar `na.omit(dados)`. Para filtrar por idade, não há necessidade do which, basta colocar as duas condições.

Comment: Boa noite, Jean. Desde já obrigado, pq a sua ajuda resolveu me um parte de problema. Nesse seu exemplo: quero um is.na que elimina todos os campos NA d qq coluna ou linha. O seu codigo só elimina a linha d idade e preciso dum q elimina também os string d letra, palavra ou frase. O filtro de idade está a dar erro, pd ela imprime as variavesi ceiadas e não as idades pedidas

Comment: Ela so elimina os NA d idade por ser n° e preciso dum codigo que elimina tb as letras, palavras ou frases das outras  colunas. No filtro de idade esse codigo  imprime as variaveis sexo, idade, unidade.organica e preciso dum codigo q apresenta todos os alunos q tem idade d 17 até 70 anos.

Comment: @Molx, vou ver como melhorar. -Evandro Lopes, como em sua questão você não deixou explicito qual/se uma operação dependia da outra, supus que a segunda embasaria-se nos resultados da primeira, vou tentar flexibilizar isto.